# How to reuse code block in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to learning javascript and apologize if this question is too basic. I have tried to search for a solution but nothing has been clear to me. I have created this code in this link.

https://jsfiddle.net/5p7wzy9x/3/

```
var btn = document.getElementById("calc");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var total = 0;
  var count = 0;
  var values = document.getElementsByClassName("value");
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var num = parseFloat(values[i].value);
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
      total += num;
      count++;
    }
  }
  output = total / count;
  var totalTb = document.getElementById("total");
  totalTb.value = count ? output : "NaN";

});

var btn = document.getElementById("calcTwo");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var total = 0;
  var count = 0;
  var values = document.getElementsByClassName("value");
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var num = parseFloat(values[i].value);
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
      total += num;
      count++;
    }
  }
  output = (total / count);
  var totalTb = document.getElementById("total");
  totalTb.value = output >= 90 ? "A" 
  : output >= 80 ? "B" 
  : output >= 70 ? "C" 
  : output >= 60 ? "D"
  : "YOU FAIL!";
});
```

My question is, how would I go about being able to use the same code for the second "grade" button without having to copy and pasting the same code?

I saw that you can use functions to invoke the same code block but am confused how I would go about it. I apologize if this question has already been answered, but I have diligently searched and tried to figure this out on my own. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Use a `function`?

Comment: Anyway, please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I did read. This is easily solved by completing a basic tutorial, unfortunately

Comment: @SterlingArcher yeah, I commented too hastily, sorry

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no worries, we just gotta close this before more high rep users try to farm it for points D:

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will certainly look into this more. I have spent some time on this, being that this is all self taught, it is hard to look at things a certain way. But anywho, Scott Marcus answered this for me.

Comment: check your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5p7wzy9x/26/), should be updated

Comment: Thank you @NinoMirzaMušić. You have made it clearer for me to see how I would go about this. Thank you again for your time and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing anonymous functions (functions with no names) to your event handlers as data:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function() { ...
```

set up those functions as **["function declarations"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)** so that you can call them by name. Then, instead of passing them into the `.addEventListner()` method call, you reference them by name (without parenthesis next to the name).

Here's an example:

```js
// Both buttons are configured to call the same event handling function:
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", doSomething);
document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", doSomething);

function doSomething(){
  console.log("Hello!");
}
```

```html
<input type=button id="btn1" value="Click Me">
<input type=button id="btn2" value="Click Me">
```

Comment: Thank you Scott Marcus, this is what I was looking for. I don't know why I couldn't see it that way. Again I am so new to all this, literally 100% self taught. Thanks again!

Comment: @Davis89 You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote the answer and mark it as "the" answer by clicking he checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Why a down vote for the answer that the OP has stated is exactly what he's looking for?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can combine common code in one function:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("calc");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("calcTwo");
var totalTb = document.getElementById("total");
  
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var output = getTotal();
  totalTb.value = output < Infinity ? output : "NaN";
});

btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var output = getTotal();
  totalTb.value = output >= 90 ? "A" 
      : output >= 80 ? "B" 
      : output >= 70 ? "C" 
      : output >= 60 ? "D"
      : "YOU FAIL!";
});

function getTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  var count = 0;
  var values = document.getElementsByClassName("value");
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var num = parseFloat(values[i].value);
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
      total += num;
      count++;
    }
  }
  output = total / count;
  return output;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <input class="value" type="text" value="80" /><br />
  <input class="value" type="text" value="50" /><br />
  <input class="value" type="text" value="15" /><br />
  <input class="value" type="text" value="30" /><br />
  <input class="value" type="text" value="90" /><br />
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="total" />
  <button type="button" id="calc">Calculate</button>
  <button type="button" id="calcTwo">Grade</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. I certainly do appreciate it.